# Where does the gap come from, and how to get rid of it?

Tags: html, css, svg

A simple document:

```css
svg {
  background-color: blue;
}
div {
  background-color: green;
}
svg, div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<svg></svg>
<div></div>
```

And just in case it's just on my system (Chrome/Mac), here's how it comes out:

[image: div and svg with a gap between them]

I can't see any margin or border on either element, but there is a gap between the two elements. And it only happens with a `svg` there: if I replace the `svg` with another `div`, no gap.

Where does it come from, and how do I make it go away?

Comment: Add `display:block;` for the svg

Comment: OMG I can't believe I overlooked `display`. Thanks.

Comment: @Quentin: I did remove whitespace, it did not help. But it is indeed solved just by setting `display: block`.